# Java AWT rotating ball

Tags: java, swing, trigonometry

Oh boy, trigonometry is so hard! I kinda need some help, It's a simple program that is supposed to rotate a ball around the center of the screen... Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Window {
private int x;
private int y;
private int R = 30;
private double alpha = 0;

private final int SPEED = 1;
private final Color COLOR = Color.red;

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    new Window().buildWindow();
}

public void buildWindow() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotation");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(new DrawPanel());
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60);
            alpha += SPEED;
            frame.repaint();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawPanel extends JPanel {


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(String.format("Angle: %.2f ", alpha), 0, 12);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(this.getWidth()/2,0, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight());
        g.drawLine(0, this.getHeight()/2, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()/2);

        x = (int) ((this.getWidth() / 2 - R / 2 ) + Math.round((R + 20) * Math.sin(alpha)));
        y = (int) ((this.getHeight() / 2 - R / 2 ) + Math.round((R + 20) * Math.cos(alpha)));

        g.setColor(COLOR);
        g.fillOval(x, y, R, R);
    }
}
}
```

This code looks like it's working, but then I've printed Angle[alpha] information to the screen. And when I comment out the `alpha+=SPEED` and enter the angle manually it does not look like it's working.The angle on the screen doses not correspond to that angle `alpha`.
So I need suggestions. What should I change? Is my trigonometry wrong? etc...

Comment: This is a classic EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) blocking issue caused by `Thread.sleep()` call. Take a look to **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219885/forcing-a-gui-update-inside-of-a-thread-jslider-updates/20220319#20220319)** for more info about avoiding use of `Thread.sleep()` in the EDT. As suggested there, use a **[Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)** to perform periodic updates.

Comment: This is wrong. There is no EDT blocking issue here. The call to `Thread.sleep()` is in the main thread, not in the EDT as in the linked question.

Comment: You're right. This is even worst. The frame creation and `repaint()` call are not made in the EDT. And OP should repaint only the `DrawPanel` object not the entire frame BTW. In any case the loop calling `Thread.sleep()` is not a good practice at all. OP should use a Swing Timer as suggested. @Grodriguez

Comment: Neither the frame creation nor the call to `repaint()` need to be made in the EDT. But in any case this has nothing to do with the original poster's question.

Comment: My comment is about suggesting good practices not a straight answer. Of course if I copy&paste this code it will work, so apparently *there's no need to create the frame in the EDT*. But thousands of examples in SO starting with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` cant't be wrong. [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Your comment started by stating that this was "a classic EDT blocking issue caused by `Thread.sleep()`" which was just wrong. That looked like an answer to me, not a suggestion of good practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things to note here:

1. I assume your `alpha` variable is in degrees since you are adding 20 in each step. However the `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` methods expect an angle in radians.
2. Normally 0 deg (or 0 rads) is represented at the "3 o'clock" position. For this you need to switch the `sin` and `cos` calls.
3. Reverse the sign in the `y` equation to account for the fact that `y` coordinates start at the top of the screen and increase downwards

With these modifications, your code will work as you expect:

```
double rads = (alpha * Math.PI) / 180F;
x = (int) ((this.getWidth() / 2 - R / 2 ) + Math.round((R + 20) * Math.cos(rads)));
y = (int) ((this.getHeight() / 2 - R / 2 ) - Math.round((R + 20) * Math.sin(rads)));
```

Comment: This is the standard way to convert from cartesian to polar coordinates, with the zero degree angle represented in the "3 o'clock" position (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)

Comment: Ok one more thing , do I need to reset the angle back to 0 when it gets to 360?(Because full circle is 360 deg)?

Comment: No need to reset the angle. Values higher than 360º are valid angles too.